# loaded run-help function code doesn't match its actual source code from disk

Tags: zsh

From the beginning of installing zsh, `run-help` was opening a man page (one of zsh sections) for the commands like `typeset`, `autoload`. Recently, I looked up the function source code at `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Misc/run-help` and noticed that help for most of these zsh commands/builtins should have been opened using a pager. After printing the actual code of the loaded function using `functions run-help`, I noticed that it was different than the actual source code.

Here are both versions and the difference between them. Notice that the second version (source code) was also output by `functions run-help` after I **kinda** fixed the problem:

### The function loaded by zsh

```bash
run-help () {
    emulate -RL zsh
    local HELPDIR="${HELPDIR:-/usr/share/zsh/5.8/help}" 
    [[ $1 == "." ]] && 1="dot" 
    [[ $1 == ":" ]] && 1="colon" 
    if [[ $# == 0 || $1 == "-l" ]]
    then
        if [[ -d $HELPDIR ]]
        then
            echo "Here is a list of topics for which special help is available:"
            echo ""
            print -rc $HELPDIR/*(:t)
        else
            echo "There is no list of special help topics available at this time."
        fi
        return 0
    elif [[ -n "${HELPDIR:-}" && -r $HELPDIR/$1 && $1 != compctl ]]
    then
        ${=PAGER:-more} $HELPDIR/$1
        return $?
    fi
    local what places noalias newline='
' 
    integer i=0 didman=0 
    places=("${(@f)$(builtin whence -va $1)}") 
    if [[ $places = *"not found"* && $1 != ${(Q)1} ]]
    then
        places=("${(@f)$(builtin whence -va ${(Q)1})}") 
        if (( ${#places} ))
        then
            set -- "${(Q)@}"
        fi
        noalias=1 
    fi
    {
        while ((i++ < $#places))
        do
            what=$places[$i] 
            [[ -n $noalias && $what = *" is an alias "* ]] && continue
            builtin print -r $what
            case $what in
                (*( is an alias for (noglob|nocorrect))*) [[ ${what[(w)7]:t} != ${what[(w)1]} ]] && run_help_orig_cmd=${what[(w)1]} run-help ${what[(w)7]:t} ;;
                (*( is an alias)*) [[ ${what[(w)6]:t} != ${what[(w)1]} ]] && run_help_orig_cmd=${what[(w)1]} run-help ${what[(w)6]:t} ;;
                (*( is a * function)) case ${what[(w)1]} in
                        (comp*) man zshcompsys ;;
                        (zf*) man zshftpsys ;;
                        (run-help) man zshcontrib ;;
                        (*) builtin functions ${what[(w)1]} | ${=PAGER:-more} ;;
                    esac ;;
                (*( is a * builtin)) case ${what[(w)1]} in
                        (compctl) man zshcompctl ;;
                        (comp*) man zshcompwid ;;
                        (bindkey|vared|zle) man zshzle ;;
                        (*setopt) man zshoptions ;;
                        (cap|getcap|setcap)  ;&
                        (clone)  ;&
                        (ln|mkdir|mv|rm|rmdir|sync)  ;&
                        (sched)  ;&
                        (echotc|echoti|sched|stat|zprof|zpty|zsocket|zstyle|ztcp) man zshmodules ;;
                        (zftp) man zshftpsys ;;
                        (*) man zshbuiltins ;;
                    esac ;;
                (*( is hashed to *)) man ${what[(w)-1]:t} ;;
                (*( is a reserved word)) man zshmisc ;;
                (*) if ((! didman++))
                    then
                        if whence "run-help-$1:t" > /dev/null
                        then
                            local cmd_args
                            builtin getln cmd_args
                            builtin print -z "$cmd_args"
                            cmd_args=(${(z)cmd_args}) 
                            while [[ $cmd_args[1] != ${run_help_orig_cmd:-$1} ]]
                            do
                                shift cmd_args || return 1
                            done
                            eval "run-help-$1:t ${(q@)cmd_args[2,-1]}"
                        else
                            POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 man $@:t
                        fi
                    fi ;;
            esac
            if ((i < $#places && ! didman))
            then
                builtin print -nP "%SPress any key for more help or q to quit%s"
                builtin read -k what
                [[ $what != $newline ]] && echo
                [[ $what == [qQ] ]] && break
            fi
        done
    } always {
        unset run_help_orig_cmd
    }
}
```

### The source code from `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Misc/run-help`

```bash
run-help () {
    emulate -RL zsh
    local HELPDIR=${HELPDIR:-/usr/share/zsh/help} 
    [[ $1 == "." ]] && 1="dot" 
    [[ $1 == ":" ]] && 1="colon" 
    if [[ $# == 0 || $1 == "-l" ]]
    then
        if [[ -d $HELPDIR ]]
        then
            echo "Here is a list of topics for which special help is available:"
            echo ""
            print -rc $HELPDIR/*(:t)
        else
            echo "There is no list of special help topics available at this time."
        fi
        return 0
    elif [[ -n "${HELPDIR:-}" && -r $HELPDIR/$1 && $1 != compctl ]]
    then
        ${=PAGER:-/usr/bin/pager} $HELPDIR/$1
        return $?
    fi
    local what places noalias newline='
' 
    integer i=0 didman=0 
    places=("${(@f)$(builtin whence -va $1)}") 
    if [[ $places = *"not found"* && $1 != ${(Q)1} ]]
    then
        places=("${(@f)$(builtin whence -va ${(Q)1})}") 
        if (( ${#places} ))
        then
            set -- "${(Q)@}"
        fi
        noalias=1 
    fi
    {
        while ((i++ < $#places))
        do
            what=$places[$i] 
            [[ -n $noalias && $what = *" is an alias "* ]] && continue
            builtin print -r $what
            case $what in
                (*( is an alias for (noglob|nocorrect))*) [[ ${what[(w)7]:t} != ${what[(w)1]} ]] && run_help_orig_cmd=${what[(w)1]} run-help ${what[(w)7]:t} ;;
                (*( is an alias)*) [[ ${what[(w)6]:t} != ${what[(w)1]} ]] && run_help_orig_cmd=${what[(w)1]} run-help ${what[(w)6]:t} ;;
                (*( is a * function)) case ${what[(w)1]} in
                        (comp*) man zshcompsys ;;
                        (zf*) man zshftpsys ;;
                        (run-help) man zshcontrib ;;
                        (*) builtin functions ${what[(w)1]} | ${=PAGER:-/usr/bin/pager} ;;
                    esac ;;
                (*( is a * builtin)) case ${what[(w)1]} in
                        (compctl) man zshcompctl ;;
                        (comp*) man zshcompwid ;;
                        (bindkey|vared|zle) man zshzle ;;
                        (*setopt) man zshoptions ;;
                        (cap|getcap|setcap)  ;&
                        (clone)  ;&
                        (ln|mkdir|mv|rm|rmdir|sync)  ;&
                        (sched)  ;&
                        (echotc|echoti|sched|stat|zprof|zpty|zsocket|zstyle|ztcp) man zshmodules ;;
                        (zftp) man zshftpsys ;;
                        (*) man zshbuiltins ;;
                    esac ;;
                (*( is hashed to *)) man ${what[(w)-1]:t} ;;
                (*( is a reserved word)) man zshmisc ;;
                (*) if ((! didman++))
                    then
                        if whence "run-help-$1:t" > /dev/null
                        then
                            local cmd_args
                            builtin getln cmd_args
                            builtin print -z "$cmd_args"
                            cmd_args=(${(z)cmd_args}) 
                            while [[ $cmd_args[1] != ${run_help_orig_cmd:-$1} ]]
                            do
                                shift cmd_args || return 1
                            done
                            eval "run-help-$1:t ${(q@)cmd_args[2,-1]}"
                        else
                            POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 man $@:t
                        fi
                    fi ;;
            esac
            if ((i < $#places && ! didman))
            then
                builtin print -nP "%SPress any key for more help or q to quit%s"
                builtin read -k what
                [[ $what != $newline ]] && echo
                [[ $what == [qQ] ]] && break
            fi
        done
    } always {
        unset run_help_orig_cmd
    }
}
```

### `diff first second`

```
3c3
<   local HELPDIR="${HELPDIR:-/usr/share/zsh/5.8/help}" 
---
>   local HELPDIR=${HELPDIR:-/usr/share/zsh/help} 
19c19
<       ${=PAGER:-more} $HELPDIR/$1
---
>       ${=PAGER:-/usr/bin/pager} $HELPDIR/$1
48c48
<                       (*) builtin functions ${what[(w)1]} | ${=PAGER:-more} ;;
---
>                       (*) builtin functions ${what[(w)1]} | ${=PAGER:-/usr/bin/pager} ;;
```

Notice how the first relied on `more` and `/usr/share/zsh/5.8/help`. Also the `help` directory from `/usr/share/zsh/5.8` was missing on my system.

### How I "fixed" it

Just modified `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Misc/run-help` by adding an echo statement at the beginning (after I removed it, anyway I think the modification of the file did solve it). After that it started loading the right version from disk every time.

### The question

Do you know what was the reason for that? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When zsh is loading the code of a function, it loads a file containing the compiled code, if available, and reads the source code otherwise. The compiled code is in either `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Misc/run-help.zwc` or `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Misc.zwc`. See the [manual on autoloading functions](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Autoloading-Functions) for more details.

If `run-help` is newer than `run-help.zwc`, zsh ignores the compiled file. So modifying `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Misc` (in any way, even a fake modification with `touch`) solved your problem. Incidentally, if the compiled file had been the directory wide `…/Misc.zwc`, this would not have solved your problem.

It appears that you upgraded zsh. Normally, if the installation procedure creates compiled files, the upgrade procedure should update these compiled files. But for whatever reason, the upgrade procedure didn't work properly.

Installing the upgraded version installed files whose modification time is the date at which the file was last modified on the machine where the package was built. This can be older than the date at which the `.zwc` file was created, which is presumably when you installed the previous version of zsh on your machine.

You might want to fully uninstall and reinstall zsh, or to arrange to recompile all the functions, since this probably affects functions other than `run-help`. You need to run the [`zcompile`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-zcompile) builtin for that. Since the installation is under `/usr`, you'll need to do that as root. Note that since zsh is installed under `/usr`, your distribution was supposed to take care of that, and doing it manually could disrupt something your distribution does.

Comment: You said that "Incidentally, if the compiled file had been the directory wide `…/Misc.zwc`, this would not have solved your problem.", but it happens that I have a `Misc.zwc` in `/usr/share/zsh/functions/` and don't have any compiled files, including `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Misc/run-help.zwc`, in the corresponding directories like `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Misc/`.
Also, I installed Zsh with `apt` on Ubuntu like 30 days ago, and it was like that since the installation, and didn't perform any upgrades to Zsh since then.

Comment: @dimm Huh, so I don't understand how changing the file would have fixed it. Are you sure it wasn't a long-running zsh session dating back from before that upgrade, and what fixed it was using a younger instance of zsh?

Comment: Pretty sure I was running the freshest `zsh` instance, because it's on my main machine which I power on every day. Also, I tested `autoload`ing behaviour and assuming `Misc/`, `Misc/run-help` and `Misc.zwc` have the same `mtime`, and the `fpath` contains `Misc`, then `touch`ing the Misc/run-help, forces `zsh` to load the function from `Misc/run-help` instead of `Misc.zwc`.